# How to create subdomain to point to a different web app

Tags: subdomain, godaddy

I have a basic Host service from godaddy. I would like to put two differnt webapps on the same Hosting, and be able to use `web1.example.com` to point to the first webapp, and the second respectively.

- What do I need for the webapp to support that ?
- What do I need for Apache server support that ?
- Is it a special feature that I probably should pay more to godaddy in order to be able to use that ?

I would like to know the whole concept of that, I am don't need a step-by-step guide, since i am just want to know what my possibilities are.

Comment: I think this question is quite localised and better for godaddy support than serverfault :)

Comment: I have mentioned godaddy just in order to implay that i am not the one who is controll every aspect of the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to configure a VHost for all the subdomains you want and point them to your webApp's directory. Considering you have access to the webserver and it is running apache ?

Your webapp normally does need to know this.

The pricing depends on Go Daddy, but that is a shopping question.